# How to fix links in the table of contents that don't redirect to the correct location

Tags: table-of-contents, links

[Translated with Google Translate, slightly edited]

I have a problem with the table of contents links in latex. ToC links do not redirect to the correct location.

Chapter numbering was restarted with `\setcounter{chapter}{0}`.

I tried to use the following code:

```
  \usepackage{chngcntr}
     \counterwithin{chapter}{part}
     \def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
```

to fix the problem with the links, but it didn't work.

Note that the EXPONENTIAL FUNCTION link, for example, is not going to the correct place in the document.

MWE:

```
%==============================================
%                PRÉÂMBULO
%==============================================
\documentclass[
10pt, % tamanho da fonte
a4paper, % tamanho do papel
twoside, % impressão frente e verso
openany, % Para iniciar capítulos em páginas pares
]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Pacote para acentuação. Não precisa, veja rodapé
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %  hifenização  
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} % Para colocar nomes das Partes, capítulos e seções em português brasil. 

\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right = 1.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry} %Para alterar as margens do documento
\usepackage[usanames, divpsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % Modifica as cores

% Para referências e informações do pdf
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks,colorlinks]{hyperref}
% Para configuração do sumário
\hypersetup{colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black,
}

% Para corrigir links do sumário
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{chapter}{part}
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

% Estilo de capítulo 
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}



% Para estilo de cabeçalho

\def\MakeUppercase{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead[]{\textit{\hspace{.1pt} \rightmark}}
\chead{}
\rhead[\textit{\hspace{.1pt} \leftmark}]{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{tocloft}

%-----------------------------------------------
%    Capa, Sumário e Lista de figuras
%-----------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}% Altera a numeração do sumário para algarismo romano
% Sumário
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\vspace{-1cm} Sumário}
\begin{center}
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{plain}
\end{center} % Cria sumário
\newpage
% Estilo de capitulo
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\raggedleft}{\fontsize{25}{60}\vspace{-3cm}\selectfont\chaptername\hspace{0.3cm}\thechapter}{0pt}{\fontsize{25}{10}\bfseries}%[\rule{0.1\linewidth}{10pt}]
%==============================================
%          INÍCIO DO DOCUMENTO
%===============================================
\pagenumbering{arabic}% Altera a numeração novamente para algarismo arábico

\part{Ensino Fundamental}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chapter{Sistemas de Numeração}
\input{A1_Sistemas de Numeração}


\newpage
\part{Ensino Médio}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{1° Ano}
\input{1° ano}
\chapter{Conjuntos}
\input{B1_Conjuntos}

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{2° Ano}
\input{2° ano}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chapter{Função Exponencial}
\input{Função Exponencial}

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{3° Ano}
\input{3° ano}
\chapter{Função Exponencial}
\input{Função Exponencial}

\end{document}
```

---

Original post in Portuguese:

**Como corrigir links no sumário que não redirecionam para o local correto**

estou com  problema nos links do sumário no latex. Os links do sumário não redirecionam para o local correto.

A numeração dos capítulos foram reinciados com `\setcounter{chapter}{0}`.

Tentei usar o

```
 \usepackage{chngcntr}
    \counterwithin{chapter}{part}
    \def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
```

para corrigir o problema com os links, mas não funcionou.

Notem que o link de FUNÇÃO EXPONENCIAL, por exemplo, não está indo para o local correto no documento.

Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor. Só falta isso para eu terminar a configuração do meu arquivo.

Segue meu MWE. Desde já agradeço toda ajuda, que Deus lhes paguem.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I suggest that you post your question in English.

Comment: What's the reason for issuing `\setcounter{chapter}{0}`? This is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to organize the document  keeping the hierarchical way using part, chapter and section to Ensino, Ano and Curso.

[image: k]

`hyperref` should generally be loaded last, one of the exceptions is `bookmark` that eases bookmark management.

The pdftex option is not needed, as it is supplied automatically when the LaTeX engine used is pdflatex.

The content of the chapters / sections was replaced with dummy text from `kantlipsum` to test the headings.

Now the links in the Sumário and the bookmarks in the pdf point to the correct pages.

Test this code:

```
\documentclass[
10pt, % tamanho da fonte
a4paper, % tamanho do papel
twoside, % impressão frente e verso
openany, % Para iniciar capítulos em páginas pares
]{book}
 %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Pacote para acentuação. Não precisa, veja rodapé
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %  hifenização  
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} % Para colocar nomes das Partes, capítulos e seções em português brasil. 

\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right = 1.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry} %Para alterar as margens do documento
\usepackage[usanames, divpsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % Modifica as cores

% Estilo de capítulo 
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\raggedleft}{\fontsize{25}{60}\vspace{-3cm}\selectfont\chaptername\hspace{0.3cm}\thechapter}{0pt}{\fontsize{25}{10}\bfseries}%[\rule{0.1\linewidth}{10pt}]

% Para estilo de cabeçalho
\def\MakeUppercase{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead[]{\textit{ \rightmark}}
\chead{}
\rhead[\textit{\leftmark}]{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % added dummy text <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

% Para referências e informações do pdf
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,colorlinks]{hyperref} % last package before bookmark
% Para configuração do sumário
\hypersetup{colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=green,
}

\usepackage{bookmark} % added <<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\vspace{-1cm} Sumário}

%-----------------------------------------------
%    Capa, Sumário e Lista de figuras
%-----------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%==============================================
%          INÍCIO DO DOCUMENTO
%===============================================
    \frontmatter %numeração do sumário romano
            
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \pdfbookmark[0]{Sumário}{toc}
    \tableofcontents    % Sumário   

    \mainmatter %numeração algarismo arábico
    \part{Ensino Fundamental}

    \chapter{Nivelamento}
    \section{Sistemas de Numeração}
    1. \kant[1-8]

    \part{Ensino Médio}
    
    \chapter{1° Ano}    
    2. \kant[2-8]

    \section{Conjuntos}         
    3. \kant[3-10]
    
    \chapter{2° Ano}    
    4. \kant[4]

    \section{Função Exponencial I}
    5. \kant[5-12]

    \chapter{3° Ano}
    6. \kant[6]
    
    \section{Função Exponencial II}
    7. \kant[7-19]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: m]

This is another possible table of contents, using non numbered chapter like

```
\chapter*{1° Ano}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{1° Ano}
```

[image: k]

Comment: I will post my question again in English

Answer (score 0):

[Sorry for being late to the party.]

With sectioning commands for creating names of targets for hyperlinks macros `\theH⟨counter⟩` are used.
The name of the target for linking to the heading of a section is made from
`⟨name of counter⟩.\theH⟨counter⟩`.
(`\HyperDestNameFilter` also affects creation of names of targets, but seems that is not an issue here.)

Thus each `\theH⟨counter⟩`-macro must initiate carrying out an expansion-based algorithm so that the results of that algorithm can be considered entries of the field "primary key" of a database which holds an entry for each item of sectioning that was created using the counter in question.

With your scenario the main problem is that the combination of the number of the part and the number of the chapter doesn't make a "primary key" for identifying each entry of a database of chapters.  This is because in the same part the chapter-counter is reset after inputting some file **X°ano.tex**.

If you step (but not necessarily print) a counter, let's call it "ano", each time a file **X°ano.tex** is input, then probably the combination of the number of the part and the value of the ano-counter and the number of the chapter probably does make a "primary key" for identifying each entry of a database of chapters.

The following example creates the dummy-files

- **A1_Sistemas de Numeração.tex**,
- **1° ano.tex**,
- **B1_Conjuntos.tex**,
- **2° ano.tex**,
- **Função Exponencial.tex**,
- **3° ano.tex**

so that `\inout`-commands work out and you can test whether navigation by clicking hyperlinks works out.

Before running the example make sure no already existing files get overridden.

This is up to you. I take no responsibility for that.

[With your minimal exhibiting example the file **Função Exponencial.tex** is input twice.  Probably this is not intended with real life scenarios.]

[In my humble opinion the intended system of numbering things does not ensure clarity on the side of the reader. But the decision is yours.]

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{A1_Sistemas de Numeração.tex}
{\huge \verb|A1_Sistemas de Numeração.tex|}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{1° ano.tex}
{\huge \verb|1° ano.tex|}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{B1_Conjuntos.tex}
{\huge \verb|B1_Conjuntos.tex|}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{2° ano.tex}
{\huge \verb|2° ano.tex|}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{Função Exponencial.tex}
{\huge \verb|Função Exponencial.tex|}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{3° ano.tex}
{\huge \verb|3° ano.tex|}
\end{filecontents*}

%==============================================
%                PRÉÂMBULO
%==============================================
\documentclass[
10pt, % tamanho da fonte
a4paper, % tamanho do papel
twoside, % impressão frente e verso
openany, % Para iniciar capítulos em páginas pares
]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Pacote para acentuação. Não precisa, veja rodapé
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %  hifenização  
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} % Para colocar nomes das Partes, capítulos e seções em português brasil. 

\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right = 1.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry} %Para alterar as margens do documento
\usepackage[usanames, divpsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % Modifica as cores

% Para referências e informações do pdf
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks,colorlinks]{hyperref}
% Para configuração do sumário
\hypersetup{colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black,
}

% Para corrigir links do sumário
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{chapter}{part}
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\newcounter{ano}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \anoinput{<file>}{<counter/sectioning-level>}{<phrase in toc>}
\newcommand\anoinput[3]{%
  \refstepcounter{ano}\addcontentsline{toc}{#2}{#3}\input{#1}%
}%
% Você precisa de um conjunto de dados que forme uma chave primária para identificar cada capítulo:
\def\theHchapter{\theHpart.\theHano.\number\value{chapter}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Estilo de capítulo 
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}



% Para estilo de cabeçalho

\def\MakeUppercase{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead[]{\textit{\hspace{.1pt} \rightmark}}
\chead{}
\rhead[\textit{\hspace{.1pt} \leftmark}]{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{tocloft}

%-----------------------------------------------
%    Capa, Sumário e Lista de figuras
%-----------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}% Altera a numeração do sumário para algarismo romano
% Sumário
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\vspace{-1cm} Sumário}
\begin{center}
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{plain}
\end{center} % Cria sumário
\newpage
% Estilo de capitulo
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\raggedleft}{\fontsize{25}{60}\vspace{-3cm}\selectfont\chaptername\hspace{0.3cm}\thechapter}{0pt}{\fontsize{25}{10}\bfseries}%[\rule{0.1\linewidth}{10pt}]
%==============================================
%          INÍCIO DO DOCUMENTO
%===============================================
\pagenumbering{arabic}% Altera a numeração novamente para algarismo arábico

\part{Ensino Fundamental}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chapter{Sistemas de Numeração}
\input{A1_Sistemas de Numeração}


\newpage
\part{Ensino Médio}
\anoinput{1° ano}{chapter}{1° Ano}
\chapter{Conjuntos}
\input{B1_Conjuntos}

\newpage
\anoinput{2° ano}{chapter}{2° Ano}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
% Really want to input the same file twice????
\chapter{Função Exponencial}
\input{Função Exponencial}

\newpage
\anoinput{3° ano}{part}{3° Ano}
\chapter{Função Exponencial}
% Really want to input the same file twice????
\input{Função Exponencial}

\end{document}
```